# Android workmanager minimum interval workaround

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I am using the workmanager to run a service in the background, minimum interval from documentation is 15 minutes, but i would like to have an interval of 2 minutes.

I tried this code, it is working while debugging from android studio and runs properly every two minutes, but once i unplug the cable, or deploy it directly via apk, it runs only one time and stops.

In main activity onCreate/onResume :

```
OneTimeWorkRequest oneTimeRequest = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(CallAndSmsWork.class).addTag(TAG).setInitialDelay(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();
        WorkManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).enqueueUniqueWork("CallnSms", ExistingWorkPolicy.REPLACE, oneTimeRequest);
```

In the end of DoWork method of CallAndSmsWork service :

```
OneTimeWorkRequest oneTimeRequest = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(CallAndSmsWork.class).setInitialDelay(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS).addTag(TAG).build();
            WorkManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).enqueueUniqueWork("CallnSms", ExistingWorkPolicy.REPLACE, oneTimeRequest);
```

Is there anything i did wrong, or any other option to have the service running properly every two minutes ?

P.S.: i am on android 10 , one plus 6t

Comment: Probably you need to use the Periodic Request https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder

Comment: @RaguSwaminathan minimum interval of PeriodicRequest is 15 minutes, i need it to run every 2 minutes

Comment: I'm not sure, what is your requirement. But general understanding is running such a background task for every 2 mins will result in the bad development approach. Running some task so frequently in background will affect the performance of your app as well will affect the device in which your app is installed. Like battery draining.. @badr slaoui

Answer (score 0):

For a 2 min interval you could use a periodic runnable, something like:

```
private val runnable = object  : Runnable {

    val periodInMillis = 2 * 60 * 1000L

    override fun run() {
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Runnable scheduled")
        // Do stuff
        mHandler?.postDelayed(this,periodInMillis)
    }
}
```

And send it to a handler thread:

```
//Threading madness
private var mThread: HandlerThread? = null
private var mHandler: Handler? = null
```

Than you can initialize:

```
//Prepare Thread
    if (mThread == null) {
        mThread = HandlerThread("HeartBeatThread", Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND)
        mThread!!.start()
    }
    if (mHandler == null) mHandler =
        Handler(mThread!!.looper) //Blocks until looper is prepared, which is fairly quick

    mHandler!!.post(runnable)
```

In this way you have a task that enqueues itself and runs every 2 minutes. The issue with that could be Doze mode and something to do with the way that Android handles battery saver mode. For that you can pick up a lock I guess.

Comment: most background methods have been deprecated as of android 10, and workmanager is definitely the way to go for all background tasks, as it is maybe the only way, to recover automatically from doze mode. I tested a delayed task for an whole night, phone not working, and in the morning the task recovered and got executed, but enqueuing a request inside a request did not work.